# Connecting to X server with xming and putty: 'xterm: Xt error: Can't open display' error troubleshooting

Tags: bash, ssh, putty, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I keep getting:

> xterm: Xt error: cannot connect to X server:[:0]

error trying to run `PGPLOT` function. I am running xmings and putty with X11 forwarding enabled.

I have tried `echo $DISPLAY` and xterm, I did get the same IPs for `$DISPLAY` but I faced this error:

> xterm: Xt error: Can't open display:[:0]

I am using Windows 11